# Firebase: is there a way to create new user with email and password without automatically logging them in on success?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I want admins to be able to signup new users. Issue is, whenever I create a new user, it logs out the admin and logs in the newly created user. Is there a way to disable the auto-login of the new user on signup?

Looking into using a cloud function to do that instead of directly from the client, but wondering if there's a way to avoid that, as I don't really need cloud functions for anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a new account was created using a client-side SDK, the user is signed in automatically. Since this is an admin operation, I suggest you use the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#create_a_user) to create new user accounts for your app.

Another option is to use [Firebase Auth REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-create-email-password) to create a new email and password user by issuing an HTTP Post request to the Auth `signupNewUser` endpoint.